# Problems Animating Two Views

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

So what I want is when the user taps on the the sideNav button two seperate animations will occur. The current view will slide out of the controller and a new view will slide in. I've set two different points of animation for the views but for some reason when the user taps on the sideNav button the views move as if they're connected. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)sideNav:(id)sender {

    if (draw1 == 0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        navView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        newsView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 568);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        navView.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 568);
        newsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint to see how many times `sideNav:` is being called. If it's accidentally being called twice then you'll get both animations completing at the same time because you're setting the `draw1` flag immediately.

Comment: Do you want first view move off the screen and once finished you want the second view to slide in? Or do you want to do both of the animation in the same time?

Comment: Thanks Travis! I'll give it a try.

I want them to both animate at the same time. I want newsView to slide off the screen and navView to slide on the screen. But the navView slide's off the screen with newsView as if it's connected with it. But I want them to be two separate animations.

Comment: Okay! I figured out the problem. I had the navView as a subview for newsView that's why it was moving with it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step toward answering your question is to simplify your code. First, unless it's used elsewhere as an integer, `draw1` should be a `BOOL`, with values of `YES` and `NO`. Second, no need for all that identical repeated code. It's much easier to understand something like:

```
- (IBAction)sideNav:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    navView.frame = draw1 ? CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 568) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    newsView.frame = draw1 ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) : CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 568);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    draw1 = !draw1;
}
```